# jQuery fadeOut not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadeout

Alright, I have the following HTML code which is for an application that is supposed to retrieve weather data from an API.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FastCast</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/footer.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon1.ico"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    <center>
    <h1><b>Welcome to FastCast!</b></h1>
    <div>
    <p><font size="3">FastCast is a web application designed to gather weather information from various sources and display it in an easy-to-read format.</font></p>
    <hr></hr>
    <div id-"all">
    <div id="picDiv">
    <img id="imgDisp" src="logo.jpg">
    </div>
    <p><font size="6">Enter you location to get started.</font></p>
    </div> 
    <form class="form-inline" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Location" placeholder="ex. Boston, MA">
    </div>
    </form>
    <p><i>Press enter to continue.</i></p>
    <script>
    window.onkeydown = function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            var x = document.getElementById("Location").value;
            var last2 = x.slice(-2);
            alert(last2);
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#all').fadeOut(1000);

            });
        }
    }
    </script>
    </div>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </center>
    </body>
    <div class="footer" id="footer">Developed in Twitter Bootstrap | Information from openweathermap.org | Tyler Jablonski, 2014+</div>
</html>
```

Right now, I'm still in the process of getting the interface set up.  Towards the end of the code, I have a bit of Javascript that alerts the last two characters in a text box when the uses presses enter.  This is working fine.  However, I  also have some jQuery after that that is supposed to fade out everything under the .  This part is not working.  I get the alert, but nothing fades out.  Why is this?

You can take a look at the page here: https://googledrive.com/host/0B7jcQuOYGlvqOHBHN3VTTi11YUU/html.html

Thanks.

Comment: you've put `div id-"all"` instead of `div id="all"`, so jQuery can't target that div

Comment: @ElendilTheTall Put it as the answer. :D

Answer (score 3):

You've put `div id-"all"` instead of `div id="all"`, so jQuery can't target that div